# Embedding Image To HTML from Database

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a scaffold which is used to update frontend information of the Home# Index. I'm unable to add the image int he given theme formate.

```
<section id="home" class="no-padding parallax mobile-height wow fadeIn" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" style="background-image:url(<%= image_tag detail.banner.url %>);">
```

Thanks.

Comment: <% @details.limit(1).each do |detail| %>
<!-- start hero section -->
<section id="home" class="no-padding parallax mobile-height wow fadeIn" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1920x1200');">
  <div class="opacity-extra-medium bg-extra-dark-gray"></div>
  <div class="container position-relative full-screen">
    <div class="slider-typography text-center">
      <div class="slider-text-middle-main xs-padding-15px-lr">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- end hero section -->

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `details.banner.url` evaluates to external url of `placehold.it/1920x1200`. If that's where the image is (which I doubt) you have to add `http://` to the link, because right now it is looking for a `placehold.it` folder and not server address. If you're trying to read a file from your server, `details.banner.url` clearly returns the wrong path. If you want to put the image in the database then look into ActiveStorage or Paperclip.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this rails guide for asset pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb)

According to this guide, your code will be like this:

```
style="background-image:url(<%= asset_path detail.banner.url %>);"
```

Comment: I'm not fetching it from my assets folder I have a form which can be used to change the image on real time without re deploying.

Comment: Need to understand how to add <%= image_tag dashboard.banner.url %> in the above code